# How to manage DSLContext in jooq? (close connection)

Tags: java, jooq

This is how I implement each jooq query that i want.

```
UtilClass{

 //one per table more or less
 static void methodA(){

  //my method
  Connection con = MySQLConnection.getConexion(); //open
  DSLContext create = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.MYSQL); //open

  /* my logic and jooq querys */ //The code !!!!!!!

  try {

    if ( con != null )
       con.close(); //close
  } catch (SQLException e) {

  } //close

  con=null; //close
  create=null; //close
 }
}
```

Am I overworking here? / Is it safe to leave the Context and Connection Open?

In case it is safe to leave it open I would rather work with 1 static field DSLContext per `UtilClass` (and only the commented section would be on my methods). I would be opening a connection for each UtilClass since I am encapsulating the methods per table (more or less).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`DSLContext` is usually not a resource, so you can leave it "open", i.e. you can let the garbage collector collect it for you.

A JDBC `Connection`, however, is a resource, and as all resources, you should always close it explicitly. The correct way to close resources in Java 7+ is by using the try-with-resources statement:

```
static void methodA() {
    try (Connection con = MySQLConnection.getConexion()) {
        DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.MYSQL); //open

        /* my logic and jooq queries */

        // "ctx" goes out of scope here, and can be garbage-collected
    }   // "con" will be closed here by the try-with-resources statement
 }
```

[More information about the try-with-resources statement can be seen here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Please also notice that the [jOOQ tutorial uses the try-with-resources statement when using standalone JDBC connections](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step6/).

#### When is `DSLContext` a resource?

An exception to the above is when you let your `DSLContext` instance manage the `Connection` itself, e.g. by passing a connection URL as follows:

```
try (DSLContext ctx = DSL.using("jdbc:url:something", "username", "password")) {
}
```

In this case, you will need to `close()` the `DSLContext` as shown above

Comment: Thanks, I understand the `try` with resources. Excellent answer. (***jOOQ** is awesome*)

Comment: Does calling `DSL.using` with a `DataSource` count as having the "`DSLContext` instance manage the `Connection` itself"? In other words, does `DSL.using(DataSource, SQLDialect)` return a `DSLContext` that needs to be closed?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: No it doesn't. Behind the scenes, `DataSourceConnectionProvider` is used, and the `Connection` is closed after each query execution, automatically, resulting in whatever semantics the `DataSource` attaches to `Connection.close()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So if I'm using a `DSLContext` created with a `DataSource `,  does 
`DSLContext.transaction` use a single JDBC `Connection` for all queries in its body and close it at the end of the transaction?

Comment: Yes. You could almost ask a new Stack Overflow question about this, where I can elaborate a bit more :)