# JDBC connection closes unexpectedly

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jooq

I'm getting the following error from time to time and I can't figure out why:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select "public"."RefreshTokens"."userId" from "public"."RefreshTokens" where "public"."RefreshTokens"."token" = ?]; This connection has been closed.
```

Here is the most important part of the stacktrace:

```
      {
        "class" : "org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection",
        "method" : "checkClosed",
        "file" : "PgConnection.java",
        "line" : 783
      }, {
        "class" : "org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection",
        "method" : "prepareStatement",
        "file" : "PgConnection.java",
        "line" : 1680
      }, {
        "class" : "org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection",
        "method" : "prepareStatement",
        "file" : "PgConnection.java",
        "line" : 371
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection",
        "method" : "prepareStatement",
        "file" : "ProviderEnabledConnection.java",
        "line" : 109
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection",
        "method" : "prepareStatement",
        "file" : "SettingsEnabledConnection.java",
        "line" : 73
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery",
        "method" : "prepare",
        "file" : "AbstractResultQuery.java",
        "line" : 239
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery",
        "method" : "execute",
        "file" : "AbstractQuery.java",
        "line" : 322
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery",
        "method" : "fetchLazy",
        "file" : "AbstractResultQuery.java",
        "line" : 393
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery",
        "method" : "fetchLazy",
        "file" : "AbstractResultQuery.java",
        "line" : 380
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery",
        "method" : "fetchOne",
        "file" : "AbstractResultQuery.java",
        "line" : 545
      }, {
        "class" : "org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl",
        "method" : "fetchOne",
        "file" : "SelectImpl.java",
        "line" : 2879
      }
```

I'm using JOOQ (3.11.11) with Postgres (42.2.5.jre7) and I create my connection and `DSLContext` like this:

```
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            config.databaseUrl, config.databaseUser, config.databasePassword)
DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
```

I thought that JOOQ would manage the connections for me and that I don't have to reopen/open/close them manually. Am I supposed to use something like `DataSource` instead of `DriverManager` for JOOQ to automatically handle the connection state? 
And it would be great if someone could tell me why the connection actually gets dropped.

Comment: You are passing jOOQ a connection, so jOOQ cannot manage the connection for you. So if the connection gets closed (eg by fatal errors or timeouts), then it won't be able to restore the connection for you.

Answer (score 1):

While `JOOQ` can somewhat manage your connections as well (using `DSL#using(String url, String username, String password)`, it usually delegates to the underlying `ConnectionProvider` or `DataSource`.

IMO, the best approach is to completely decouple `JOOQ` (as the *executor* using the connections) and your connection manager (as the *manager* that oversees connection opening and closing).

One way to do this is using a `DataSource`, `org.jooq.Configuration#derive(DataSource dataSource)` and `DSL#using(Configuration configuration)` as follows:

```
javax.sql.DataSource ds = ...; // initialize DataSource
org.jooq.Configuration configuration = Configuration.derive(ds);
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(configuration);

Record r = dslContext.selectFrom(...).where.(...).fetchOne();
```

See also the [DSL javadocs](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.0/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-org.jooq.Configuration-) as well as the [Configuration javadocs](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.11.0/org/jooq/Configuration.html#derive-javax.sql.DataSource-) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773698/how-to-manage-dslcontext-in-jooq-close-connection) answer.

Comment: Coming from you, that's quite a compliment for a question on jOOQ! :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the `DataSource` part?